# Python Hierarchy passing a function

Tags: python, class-hierarchy

```
try: Polygon
except: from Polygon import Polygon

class Triangle(Polygon):

def __init__(self, width, height):

    sides = 3
    super().__init__(sides, width)

#        self.__side2 = s2
#        self.__side3 = s3
    self.__height = height

def get_height(self):
    """Returns height"""
    return self.__height    

def set_height(self, height):
    """Sets the height"""
    if height <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Height must be positive')
    self.__height = height
try: Triangle
except: from Triangle import Triangle, Polygon
```

child class

```
class IsocelesTriangle(Polygon):

def __init__(self, width, height):

#      sides = 3

    super().__init__ (width, height)

def get_area(self):
    """Gets the area of an isoceles triangle"""
    area = ((1/2) * (self.get_width()) * (self.get_height()))
    return area

def get_perimeter(self):
    """Returns the are of an isoceles triangle"""
    p = (2 * self.get_width()) + self.get_height()
    return p
```

So I am having an issue where the Triangle class is higher than the IsocelesTriangle class, there is a polygon class higher up and i get the width from that. However I have been trying for hours to get the height out of the triangle into the IsocelesTriangle class but it keeps throwing:

```
AttributeError: 'IsocelesTriangle' object has no attribute 'get_height'
```

Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your isosceles class inherits from Polygon, not Triangle.  Where do you expect it to get the `get_height` method from?

Comment: I spent over an hour knowing i had everything right. Thanks

Comment: BTW: Are you aware of the classig OOP question how to model circle and ellipse or rectangle and square? It looks as if your two triangles have similar issues... That said, you should have spent ten minutes extracting a minimal(!) example. I'm sure you would have noticed your mistake.

Comment: Yes but I'm just trying to get it to work now. Had I given everything a more generic way it would have helped. I'll revise as I go along and have the time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `IsocelesTriangle` doesn't inherit from your `Triangle` class. Instead it is inheriting from `Polygon`. Therefore it would not see the `get_height` function.